# Unnesting a data frame containing lists

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I have a data frame that contains lists, like below:

```r
# Load packages
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, 
                     A = structure(list(c(9, 8), c(7,6), c(6, 9)), ptype = numeric(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr")), 
                     B = structure(list(c(3, 5), c(2, 6), c(1, 5)), ptype = numeric(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr")), 
                     C = structure(list(c(6, 5), c(7, 6), c(8, 7)), ptype = numeric(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr")), 
                     D = structure(list(c(5, 3), c(4, 1), c(6,  5)), ptype = numeric(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr"))), 
                row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Peek at data 
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      ID A         B         C         D        
#>   <int> <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
#> 1     1 <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 2     2 <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 3     3 <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
```

I'd like to unnest the lists and can do so using `pmap_dfr`.

```r
# Expand rows
df %>% purrr::pmap_dfr(function(...)data.frame(...))
#>   ID A B C D
#> 1  1 9 3 6 5
#> 2  1 8 5 5 3
#> 3  2 7 2 7 4
#> 4  2 6 6 6 1
#> 5  3 6 1 8 6
#> 6  3 9 5 7 5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is the desired result, but seems to be reinventing the wheel because `tidyr::unnest` is designed to flatten list columns back to regular columns. Using `tidyr::unnest` produces the following error, however:

```r
df %>% unnest(cols = c(A, B, C, D))
#Error: No common type for `x` <tbl_df<A:double>> and `y` <double>.
#Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

How would I apply `unnest` in this case for flattening my data frame with list columns?

---

#### Version information

```r
> packageVersion("tidyr")
[1] ‘0.8.3.9000’
```

Comment: I see no difference between `unnest(df)` and `pmap_dfr(df, data.frame)`, both are your intended output (though the latter is not a `tbl_df`).

Comment: @r2evans Weird. `unnest` throws an error for me. Then again, I'm using the development version of `tidyr`...

Comment: Mine is `tidyr-0.8.2`, perhaps you have a new [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues)?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, I'll create an issue. Is SO protocol to delete a question due to a bug in a dev version or leave it?

Comment: I experience the same issue with tidyr development version. Turning your columns into ordinary lists solves the issue for me: `df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(A:D), as.list) %>% unnest(cols = A:D)`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the syntax `unnest(df, cols = c(A, B, C, D))`, and it doesn't work for my version of tidyr either. Is that maybe the issue? `unnest(df)` and `unnest(df, A, B, C, D)` are equivalent and work fine.

Comment: I think keeping it here for the time being is actually relevant, as others may have similar questions, and seeing these comments will be incredibly useful. Depending on the response-time on github (not sure when the devs' attention will roll back around to `tidyr`), you might post an answer here stating (1) it's a current bug, and (2) here are one or two workarounds for the time being. Then later you can (3) update when the github/CRAN versions have been fixed. Thanks, nice find!

Comment: I also think cross-linking both the issue and the SO question would be a good thing.

Comment: @gersht Perhaps this is new, but omitting `cols` in the dev version produces `Warning message: 'cols' is now required. Please use 'cols = c(A, B, C, D)' `

Comment: An issue is now filed on github [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/658#issue-462153556).

Comment: After playing around a bit I've come to the conclusion that there probably isn't any issue, I think `nest` has just become more focused and that `chop` has taken over some of its duties. See my answer below and let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks, @gersht — I'll have a think about it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: Hadley Wickham has flagged this issue on github as a bug in tidyr version 0.8.3.9000 (see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/658#issue-462153556)). I'll leave the below answer as a potential workaround until the issue is fixed.

It looks like `nest` is more specifically used to create list-columns of dataframes in 0.8.3.9000. From the docs: *Nesting creates a list-column **of data frames**; unnesting flattens it back out into regular columns.*. For example, try:

```r
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), y = 1:6, z = 6:1) %>% 
    nest(data = c(y, z))
```

Which returns:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x           data
  <dbl> <list<df[,2]>>
1     1            [2]
2     2            [2]
3     3            [2]
```

Then look at `df$data`:

```r
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    y: integer
    z: integer
  >
>[3]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      y     z
  <int> <int>
1     1     6
2     2     5
3     3     4

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      y     z
  <int> <int>
1     4     3
2     5     2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      y     z
  <int> <int>
1     6     1
```

Your dataframe's columns are list-columns of vectors, which seem to fall under purview of `chop`, which shortens a dataframes while preserving their width. For example, try:

```r
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), y = 1:6, z = 6:1) %>% 
    chop(c(y, z))
```

Which returns:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x y         z        
  <dbl> <list>    <list>   
1     1 <int [3]> <int [3]>
2     2 <int [2]> <int [2]>
3     3 <int [1]> <int [1]>
```

And take a look at `df$y`:

```r
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

Knowing this, the appropriate method for your data would be `chop`'s counterpart `unchop`, so given your dataframe:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID           A           B           C           D
  <int> <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>
1     1         [2]         [2]         [2]         [2]
2     2         [2]         [2]         [2]         [2]
3     3         [2]         [2]         [2]         [2]
```

Try `unchop(df, c(A, B, C, D))` or `unchop(df, A:D)`, which should return:

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID     A     B     C     D
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     9     3     6     5
2     1     8     5     5     3
3     2     7     2     7     4
4     2     6     6     6     1
5     3     6     1     8     6
6     3     9     5     7     5
```

Comment: +1 for the thoughtful solution, but Hadley has now flagged it as a bug. Thanks for taking the time to think about this.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Lyngbakr. I've added a note pointing out that it is likely a bug, but I'll leave the answer just in case it helps someone.