# How to convert string to numeric to sum values in one cell in R?

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have a dataset with two values in a cell/column per row:

```
Gene  Count
ACE     1,2
BRCA    3,7
HER2    100,300
```

I am trying to sum the numbers in each row of the count column to output:

```
Gene  Count
ACE     3
BRCA    10
HER2    400
```

I've been trying to build something to get the numeric values but I don't know how to then specify the addition of values per row:

```
getnum = function(col) str_extract_all(col,"[0-9\\.-]+") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x)as.numeric(x) ) %>%
  unlist()
```

Any help or suggestions on what to use would be appreciated.

Input data:

```
structure(list(Gene = c("ACE", "BRCA", "HER2"), Count = c(3L, 
10L, 400L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your *Input data* is actually your *output data*.

Answer (score 2):

Straight in base R:

```
df$Count <- sapply(strsplit(df$Count, ","), function(x) sum(as.integer(x)))
df

#   Gene Count
# 1  ACE     3
# 2 BRCA    10
# 3 HER2   400
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Gene = c("ACE", "BRCA", "HER2"), 
  Count = c("1,2", "3,7", "100,300")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution, may not be the best, for your reference.

```
library("dplyr")

data %>% 
  group_by(row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(Count2 = sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(Count, ","))))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-"row_number()")
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Gene  Count   Count2
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 ACE   1,2          3
2 BRCA  3,7         10
3 HER2  100,300    400
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the numbers from `Count`, convert to numeric and `sum`.

This can be done using `stringr`

```
sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$Count, '\\d+'), function(x) sum(as.integer(x)))
#[1]   3  10 400
```

Or base R :

```
sapply(regmatches(df$Count, gregexpr('\\d+', df$Count)), function(x) sum(as.integer(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could change the comma to a plus and evaluate the string:

```
sapply(df$Count, function(x) eval(parse(text = gsub(",", "+", x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- fread('Gene  Count
ACE     1,2
BRCA    3,7
HER2    100,300')

sum_num <- function(col){
unlist(lapply(strsplit(col,","),function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))))
}


dt[,result:=sum_num(Count)][]
#>    Gene   Count result
#> 1:  ACE     1,2      3
#> 2: BRCA     3,7     10
#> 3: HER2 100,300    400
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned converting string to numeric and summing. You've gotten answers for that. I wanted to point out another possibility.

In your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890939/how-to-conditionally-count-and-record-if-a-sample-appears-in-rows-of-another-dat), you wanted to generate output that also contained items separated by commas. The answers included generating that column from `data.table` directly such that the column actually contains a list of values.

If in this case, your dataset had been constructed similarly from `data.table`, you wouldn't have a character string with a comma, rather a column of lists. (The comma shows up in the printout for convenience.)

The summation would be straightforward.

```
library(data.table)
# create such a dataset 
y <- data.table(Gene=c("ACE","BRCA","HER2"),
                Count1=c(1,3,100),
                Count2=c(2,7,300))
D <- y[,.(Gene=rep(Gene,2),x=c(Count1,Count2))] 
D <- D[,.(Count=list(x)),by=Gene] 
D

# convert Count to the sum      
D[,Count:=sapply(Count,sum)]
D
```

Maybe this isn't applicable to your actual case, but I thought I'd mention it.